# How can I control what happens after an update?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, p2

The latest version of our RCP application has a bug that leads to the application process not being destroyed during a restart after an update. It happens because, during an after-update restart, some Eclipse shutdown routines simply don't get run.

As we have some code that blocks multiple executions, the restart does not happen. On Windows, the user must open the Task Manager and manually kill the process.

Given this scenario, we are looking for ways to achieve one of the following:

1. Not showing the "do you wish to restart now?" dialog to the user after the update. This way the user will have to manually close and restart the application, leading to the execution of those specific Eclipse shutdown routines.
2. Force the execution of the Eclipse shutdown routines after the update.

Is there a way to do any of those two?

Comment: IN THE ARGUMENTS SECTION PLEASE ADD -clearPersistedState

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  Where is this section and what does this argument do?

Comment: Should be in run configurations what is does is something you should read ... please google it ...